# Use GS Query() to convert text value into a number

Tags: sql, google-sheets

Consider a table, in which column A is an entity associated with column B. And column B contains numbers in text formats (e.g., 3.0000 is a text).

I've tried this query:

```
=QUERY(range_name,"SELECT A, VALUE(B)",0).
```

I've also tried this query:

```
=QUERY(range_name,"SELECT A, B*1",0).
```

Neither works. I'm able within google sheets to convert it by multiplying (B*1), but I'd prefer to do this within the query.

Any ideas? I'm tagging SQL as well as google sheets, though quite a few SQL functions don't work in GS.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do it inside the range?

```
=QUERY({A:A,INDEX(VALUE(B:B))},"Select Col1, Col2",0)
```

Obviously if you just need the data without any further processing, you can get rid of "Select Col1, Col2" part

Comment: Yes, This works. BUT ... it'd be better if there were some like of direct conversion because this reorders my columns, such that what was A, B, C, D is now A, B, C, D, VALUE(B). Not a disaster, but my other sheets are built around the present ABCD order and ranges. But again, it DOES work, and it will ultimately solve my problem if I can't find another way.

Comment: I've never had luck with conversion inside the QUERY. Options: `=QUERY({A:A,INDEX(VALUE(B:B)),C:D})` Or `=QUERY({A:D,INDEX(VALUE (B:B))},"SELECT Col1,Col5,Col3,Col4")` - these should allow you the order correctly the columns. Let me know!